# Grouping and merging keys using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have the following json file that looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "data": {
      "location": {
        "info": [
          {
            "folder": {
              "path": "/home/ip1"
            },
            "key": {
              "id": "1234",
              "label": "home"
            }
          },
          {
            "folder": {
              "path": "/home/ip2"
            },
            "key": {
              "id": "5678",
              "label": "office"
            }
          },
          {
            "folder": {
              "path": "/home/ip1"
            },
            "key": {
              "id": "1001",
              "label": "office"
            }
          },
          {
            "folder": {
              "path": "/home/ip1"
            },
            "key": {
              "id": "1002",
              "label": "office"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Now I'd like to group and key that by "folder/path" and assign a list of id's to each of the path:

```json
[
  {
    "path": "/home/ip1",
    "id": [
      "1234",
      "1001",
      "1002"
    ]
  },
  {
    "path": "/home/ip2",
    "id": [
      "5678"
    ]
  }
]
```

I try using jq group_by and map:

```
jq '. | group_by(.data.location.info[].folder.path) | map({ path: (.[0].path), id: [.[] | .id] })' json_file
```

but it returns null values.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You almost had it right, with a few modifications on the nodes that you are applying the `group_by` on

```
jq '.[].data.location.info | group_by(.folder.path) | 
    map({ path: (.[0].folder.path), id: [.[].key.id] })' json
```

See [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/YoGfXVhmsf8) on jqplay

Answer (score 0):

[custom group functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73893818/function-to-group-by-but-return-an-object-with-group-as-key) to the rescue!

```
def group(f):
  group_by(f) | map({key:first|f, value:.}) | from_entries;
  
.[].data.location.info
| group(.folder.path)
| map_values(map(.key.id))
```

- `.[].data.location.info`: get infos. obvious.
- `| group(.folder.path)`: build object with folder path as key
- `| map_values(map(.key.id))`: only keep id of the group values